# KeyError in Django REST's POST request only occurs when sent from frontend but not when sent from postman

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios

### Frontend

This is my code in the frontend. In short, it fetches the bing queries from third-party api, maps through the results to create a new array, and makes a POST request to Django REST

```
  axios
    .get(
      "exampleapi.bing.com/query",
      { withCredentials: true }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      const webPages = response.data.webPages.value.map((page: any) => ({
        id: nextId(),
        documentId: draftId,
        url: page.url,
        title: page.name,
        desc: page.snippet,
        isNews: false,
      }));
      
      console.log('webPages: ', webPages);
      axios
        .post(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/v1/recsources/`,
          {
            data: webPages,
          },
          { withCredentials: true }
        )
        .catch(AxiosCatch);
    })
    .catch(AxiosCatch);
```

This is what I see when I console.log the webPages right before I make the POST request,

```
[
    {
        "id": "id19",
        "documentId": "AVD4Mpy",
        "url": "https://www.verywellmind.com/social-media-and-depression-5085354",
        "title": "The Link Between Social Media and Depression - Verywell Mind",
        "desc": "Studies also indicate that social media may trigger an array of negative emotions in users that contribute to or worsen their depression symptoms. Defining Depression Clinical depression or major depressive disorder is a mood disorder characterized by ongoing feelings of sadness and loss of interest in activities that an individual once enjoyed.",
        "isNews": false
    },
    {
        "id": "id20",
        "documentId": "AVD4Mpy",
        "url": "https://www.tuw.edu/school-news/does-social-media-cause-depression/",
        "title": "Does Social Media Cause Depression? | Study Media Psychology",
        "desc": "Recent research seems to link excessive social network usage to many mental health problems, including depression, anxiety, and low self-esteem. Social media also is associated with reduced attention span, sleep difficulties, and hyperactivity.",
        "isNews": false
    }
]
```

Then, I get this KeyError during the POST request, which I think it happens because the django serializer cannot read "documntId" field from request data.

```
File "/code/scraft-server/documents/serializers.py", line 59, in create
    documentId = validated_data.pop("documentId")
    KeyError: 'documentId'
```

The weird thing is, making the POST request with the same `webPages` in Postman works with no problem. It only displays the KeyError in the actual typescript code.

---

### Backend

This is the code for django REST:

#### models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    id = HashidAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Untitled")

class RecSource(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    document = models.ForeignKey(
        Document,
        related_name="rec_source_cards",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    documentId = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="docId", blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True)
    isNews = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

#### serializer.py

```
class RecSourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    document = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        pk_field=HashidSerializerCharField(source_field="documents.Document.id"),
        read_only=True,
    )
    documentId = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = RecSource
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        documentId = validated_data.pop("documentId")
        recsource = RecSource.objects.create(
            document=Document.objects.get(id=documentId), **validated_data
        )
        recsource.save()
        return recsource
```

#### views.py

```
class RecSourceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = RecSource.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecSourceSerializer
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsRecSourceOwner,)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data, list)
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(
            serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by changing the axios.post code from this:

```
axios
    .post(
      `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/v1/recsources/`,
      {
        data: webPages,
      },
      { withCredentials: true }
    )
    .catch(AxiosCatch);
```

To this

```
axios
    .post(
      `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/v1/recsources/`,
      webPages
      { withCredentials: true }
    )
    .catch(AxiosCatch);
```